# Remove duplicate in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe known as `Tgame` containing two columns `game` and `hours_played`. I am trying to remove duplicates in the column `game` and also sum up the average for column `hours_played` for game column.

Comment: Please give a [mre] in your question! Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this (using `data.table`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Tgame)[, mean(hours_played), by = game]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. one question then how do you check the top 20 games with high hours played

Comment: @FeniboTonye Assuming you have used the solution above then `Tgame[order(hours_played, decreasing = TRUE)][1:20]` should do.

Comment: How about to write a code to show hours played >= 14 and show only 20 result

Comment: so i got the mean hours_played from that first code help. now how do i check the tp 10 high mean

Comment: If you have another question then please search for the answer here on Stackoverflow and Google and if you cannot find it open a new question.